# How to catch pages ids and showing the selected ones?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

I have 7 pages about services.

In documentation of Redux Framework explain the class [`select` and `multi select`](https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/select/)

Example Multi Select code:

```
$fields = array(
    'id'       => 'opt-multi-select',
    'type'     => 'select',
    'multi'    => true,
    'title'    => __('Multi Select Option', 'redux-framework-demo'), 
    'subtitle' => __('No validation can be done on this field type', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'desc'     => __('This is the description field, again good for additional info.', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    //Must provide key => value pairs for radio options
    'options'  => array(
        '1' => 'Opt 1',
        '2' => 'Opt 2',
        '3' => 'Opt 3'),
    'default'  => array('2','3')
);
```

How I do for in `options` insert dynamically all pages ids or posts ids registered in DB?

**UPDATED**

```
Redux::setSection($opt_name, array(
    'id' => 'options_services',
    'title' => 'Services',
    'subsection' =>  true,
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'id'       => 'opt-multi-select_pages',
            'type'     => 'select',
            'multi'    => true,
            'title'    => 'Multi Select Option', 
            'data'     => 'pages', // select pages
            'args'     => array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 ),
            'default'  => array('1','2','3','4','5')
        )
    )

));
```

index.php

```
<?php 
    foreach ($global_master['options_services'] as $singleValue){
?>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="service-item">
            <h4> <strong><?php echo $singleValue['post_title'] ?> </strong></h4>
            <img src="<?php echo $singleValue['post_thumbnail_url'] ?>" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
            <a href="<?php echo $singleValue['guid'] ?>" class="btn btn-light">See More</a>
        </div>
    </div>


<?php
    }
?>
```

The above code does not return anything in the index

In the code I Try use [returns 'post_title' and 'guid'](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) indicated in documentation wordpress and not have references of 'post_thumbnail_url.'

**UPDATED 2**

I was able to solve my initial doubt with the help of Nathan Dawson and to print I used the code below:

```
<?php 
    foreach ($global_master['opt-multi-select_pages'] as $singleValue){

            $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($singleValue);
            $post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );

?>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="service-item service">
            <h4> <strong><?php echo get_the_title($singleValue); ?> </strong></h4>
            <img src="<?php echo $post_thumbnail_url; ?>" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink($singleValue); ?>" class="btn btn-light">See more</a>
        </div>
    </div>



<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields in the Redux Framework have the option to dynamically list pages out of the box, you simply need to set the argument. Drop 'options' and set a value for 'data' instead.

Example:

```
$fields = array(
    'id'       => 'opt-multi-select',
    'type'     => 'select',
    'multi'    => true,
    'title'    => __('Multi Select Option', 'redux-framework-demo'), 
    'subtitle' => __('No validation can be done on this field type', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'desc'     => __('This is the description field, again good for additional info.', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'data'     => 'pages', // select pages
    'args'     => array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 ),
    'default'  => array('2','3')
);
```

You may notice I've also added the 'args' option. The pages 'data' option will retrieve 20 by default, the custom args retrieve all pages instead.

Documentation: https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/the-basics/using-data-argument/

Comment: Thanks, this really is great, please how do I display in a foreach the title and thumbnail of the pages? Please, see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
//$page_id_array store your all page ids
$page_id_array = get_all_page_ids();
//$options will store multi select options.
$options = array();

foreach( $page_id_array as $page_id ){
    $options[$page_id] = get_the_title($page_id);
}

$fields = array(
    'id'       => 'opt-multi-select',
    'type'     => 'select',
    'multi'    => true,
    'title'    => __('Multi Select Option', 'redux-framework-demo'), 
    'subtitle' => __('No validation can be done on this field type', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'desc'     => __('This is the description field, again good for additional info.', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    //Must provide key => value pairs for radio options
    'options'  => $options,
    'default'  => array('2','3'),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution